# How to add bottom arrow at the top of each div in html/css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add a bottom arrow image at the the top of every div section of my web page.I want the bottom arrow to be centered as in http://jirungu2012.wix.com/firebrandoption2

Each section has a different bottom arrow color

Comment: look into http://cssarrowplease.com/ for how to do it or provide the codethat you have tried to help you

Comment: Please show your working if you are having trouble with the standard way to add CSS arrows.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an image or you could use CSS. Here is a quick example with the green span line to show that it is centred. In future please show your attempts in your question and add more detail.

```css
div{
  width:500px;
  height:200px;
  background-color:blue;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}
div::before{
  content:" ";
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent; 
  border-top: 20px solid #f00;
  position:absolute;
  left:50%;
  transform:translateX(-50%)
}
span{
  position:absolute;
  left:50%;
  width:1px;
  height:100%;
  background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<div>
<span></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.solidArea{
  width:100%;
  height:20px;
  background-color:lightblue;
  margin: ;
}
.arrow-down {
 width: 0; 
 height: 0; 
 border-left: 20px solid transparent;
 border-right: 20px solid transparent;
 border-top: 20px solid #fff;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="solidArea">
  <div align="center">
  <div class="arrow-down "></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

There you go..